How can i Sync in unity objects that are already in the scene?
I have a gameobject in my scene, with a key press I can add child objects. Now, how can I take the childobjects and sync them to the client with mirror?
I tried NetworkServer.Spawn() and NetworkServer.SpawnObjects(). Also I tried to clone the gameobject with the children but that also didn't work.
